# Columns in view that will calculate remaining days in Lotus Notes Designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Is there a way to add a column in a Lotus Notes View that will calculate the remaining days?

EXP Date - Today's date = Rem. Days

```
| EXP Date  | Rem. Days |

| 9/01/2019 |     30    |
```

Assuming today's date is 8/01/2019

[Inside view in designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Psi.png)

[Actual wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60kae.png)

Answer (score 5):

By definition, subtracting two date values gives the number of seconds between the two dates. Divide by 86400 and round up if necessary, to get the number of days.

On the other hand, this is not the right way to do this. Each time the view is opened, the column is recalculated. If the number of documents is low, it's fast enough, but if you have a large number of documents your view might become virtually unusable.

The alternative would be to have an agent calculate the number of days, but only once per day, e.g. during the night, and put that value in the document.

Comment: Another option is to create an agent that hard-codes the date into the view's selection formula on a nightly basis, then refreshes the view.  This is how I currently set a variety of views that require today's date in our organisation, who fortunately only operate in one time-zone.

Comment: How about column that will calculate the data that will expire in 3 months? same case? Thanks!

Comment: See the @Adjust function, e.g. @Adjust(value; 0; 3; 0; 0; 0; 0)

Comment: @BusinessDays is your friend here!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Date functions (@Today, @Now) in Views! This might result in a impressive performance loss. 
Create an agent which updates a field and display this field in the view.